# Centering 3 different size navbar elements using vanilla CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

Sorry if this question has been posted already. I've only found solutions to this that use Bootstrap or tackle similar issues but not quite the same. I need to solve this with vanilla CSS.

I have a navbar with 3 different elements like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJHlQ.jpg

I centered everything using flexbox which worked fine except my left and my right elements are of different width. So the logo is centered between them perfectly albeit that means it's a little off to the right relative to the container. How do I make the logo centered relative to the container no matter what yet make it responsive?

I've been trying to fix this for hours now but only came up with a hacky way like inserting an invisible element to create extra margin on the right. Is there an easy fix I'm not seeing?

Here's the chuck of code:

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid red;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  align-items: center;
  
}

.nav__list--primary {
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.nav__list--secondary {
  gap: 6rem;
  border: 1px solid blue; 
}

.navbar__item--icon {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">

      <ul class="nav__list nav__list--primary row">
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="text--black" href="#">SHOP</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="text--black" href="#">VISIT US</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="text--black" href="#">EVERYTHING ELSE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" class="navbar__item logo text--black">
        GRIND
      </a>

      <ul class="nav__list nav__list--secondary row">
        <li class="navbar__item--icon">
          <a class="text--black" href="#">
            <i class="bx bx-user-circle"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item--icon">
          <a class="text--black" href="#">
            <i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use grid on the nav element, justifying their content left, center and right respectively.

Here's the code you have given with that change:

```css
.nav {
  /*display: flex;*/
  border: 2px solid red;
  /* justify-content: space-between; */
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.nav> :nth-child(2) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.nav> :nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}

.nav__list--primary {
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.nav__list--secondary {
  gap: 6rem;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.navbar__item--icon {
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

.logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  margin-bottom: 6rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="nav">

      <ul class="nav__list nav__list--primary row">
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="text--black" href="#">SHOP</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="text--black" href="#">VISIT US</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar__item">
          <a class="text--black" href="#">EVERYTHING ELSE</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" class="navbar__item logo text--black">
            GRIND
          </a>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav__list nav__list--secondary row">
          <li class="navbar__item--icon">
            <a class="text--black" href="#">
              <i class="bx bx-user-circle"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__item--icon">
            <a class="text--black" href="#">
              <i class="bx bx-shopping-bag"></i>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>enter code here
```

Note: the third child was wrapped in a div so that the (smaller actual) content can be shown with its border rather than the whole 1fr being bordered.